# Which fab for DRAM device? (ASIC design at Europractice)

Tags: asic, dram

I would like to ask for advice.

Europractice supports many fabs and technologies for custom asic design ([fab list](http://europractice-ic.com/technologies.php)). Lib support list of those technologies are public (for example [UMC 130 nm LL](http://europractice-ic.com/docs/UMC_L130_LL_Process.jpg)). I checked all of public lists, and nowhere found dram support.

I am looking for opportunity to design a dram device (for example on 130 nm if that is possible). Which fab i should sign for?

Comment: Like I told you in another question, DRAM requires a special process. Only a few factories make DRAM. I doubt that there are any MPW possibilities on a DRAM process. Almost all MPWs are CMOS based and you cannot make proper DRAM in CMOS.

Comment: @FakeMoustache: It would certainly not be possible to make DRAM with anything near the density of a mass-market DRAM without using processes optimized for that.  On the other hand, I would think that a three-cell dynamic memory design might be more compact than a static design.  The storage element would be the gate of a MOSFET #1 whose source is grounded.  That gate would be connected to a "write" bus through MOSFET #2 and, and the drain of MOSFET #1 is connected to a read bus through MOSFET #3.

Comment: @FakeMoustache I got it. I want dram, that requires spec technology, what no one else would use, so no design cost advantage for me by mpw based offers. Even if i lost that advantage, Europractice offers a way to get insight into front end design steps for easy, and that is the advantage i would go for. Problem is, i cannot recognize, what i need. Is there any fab / technology on Europractice's list i should look for?

Comment: @supercat do you mean something like design on start of that document ( http://ece.ut.ac.ir/classpages/F84/AdvancedVLSI/Lecture%20Notes/chapter12-2.pdf ) "3-Transistor DRAM Cell"?

Comment: @cocox: That's exactly what I was thinking of.  Nowhere near the density of one-transistor DRAM cells, but if one needs to get a large amount of memory on the same die as everything else and can afford the power consumption and access limitations it would seem like such a design should achieve pretty good density.  I'm not sure what the maximum refresh time would be, or how big the banks could be, but I would expect that a layout which used groups of 16 rows could achieve a good space savings compared to a static design, and would probably be reliable if rows were refreshed every few us.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can multi-project wafer service merge projects with different number of layers?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/293853/can-multi-project-wafer-service-merge-projects-with-different-number-of-layers)

Comment: @winny i dont know what do you mean. Marked question was about a concepction opportunity for an answer of simple yes or no, even if threads there wandered a bit away, because of question was not simple to answer. This one question is about which fabs nda to sign to start front end design of a project. I dont know why you flagged this question to that. There is no logical connection between the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DRAM processes are usually just mean that you have a trench capacitor with a high density pattern option.  I know for a fact that those GF processes in your list have a trench capacitor, and I'm confident that the other 40nm or smaller nodes will as well.  I use DRAM instead of SRAM when I need more than about 6MiB because the charge-amps required for SRAM end up using more power than the DRAM refresh.

As an example, [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/210576/why-dram-costs-much-more-than-flash-memory/210584#210584) has an illustration of my work from a 14nm SOI process where I get about 8-bits DRAM per the area of a single FLASH gate (non-FLASH process), which is about the same area as the cost of 2-bits of SRAM.

Here's the kicker, you will need the NDAs to see what is actually in the design kits.  For example, the GF 24nm white paper only lists a fraction of the devices that I see in the kit.

Comment: (Sry for previously deleted posts here.) I would like to ask for even more advice. I downloaded NDA request form for GlobalFoundries from EuroPractice website, and form demands me to choose technology, i want access for. There are technologies with exact name in range of 22nm .. 55nm (for example "22FDX", "28SLP", "55LPx-NVM") and "Other" option. I not found exact technology names on GF website, neither i know how to ask them about what EP will recognize. I would use 110 or 130 nm to design a dram, and looking for exact technology name for that. Where can i find exact technology name(s) ?

Comment: @cocox Well, it'll be an option on the process.  The suffix usually just shows whether it is a high speed, low power, analog, etc process.  You should just ask for the 130nm (the feature size is much smaller than that) and see what options you have.  Also, I don't know if 130nm has trench caps, but I've  not been on that process in ages.